# How to use ViewBag to pass list of data from View to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

how can i sen a list of items from a view to a controller to save it. i believe that i can use Viewbag  but i dont realy no how to use ite to pass data from view to controller.

this is what i have tried
My view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>ProductionOrderItem</legend>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("ProducrionOrderNo");
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("ProductionOrderNo", ViewBag.ProductionOrder as int)

    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
       @Html.Label("OrderName")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("OrderName", ViewBag.ProductionOrder as string)
    </div>
 <div class="editor-label">
       @Html.Label("OrderDate")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("OrderDate", ViewBag.ProductionOrder as DateTime)
</div>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

and my controller

```
   [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
     {
        ProductionRegistration pr = new ProductionRegistration();
        ProductionItem poi = new ProductionItem();

         poi = Viewbag.ProductionOrder;

         pr.SaveOrder(Conn, poi);
         return RedirectToAction("Index");

     }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't pass data from ViewBag/ViewData *to* the controller. It's one-way only (controller to view). The only way to get data back to the controller is to post it (post-body) or send it along in a querystring.

In fact, you should really avoid ViewBag as much as possible. It was added as a convenience and like most convenience methods, it's abused more often than not. Use a view model to both pass data to the view and accept data back from a post.

You strongly-type your view with:

```
@model Namespace.For.My.OrderViewModel
```

Then, you can use the `[Foo]For` methods of Razor to build your fields in a strongly-typed way:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductionOrderNo);
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductionOrderNo)
</div>
```

And finally in your post action, you accept the view model as a param:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OrderViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

And let MVC's modelbinder wire up the posted data for you.

No more dynamics. Everything is strongly-typed end-to-end, so if something goes wrong, you'll know it at *compile-time*, not *run-time*.

Comment: you mean by <form nwthod="post" action="Controller/AcionMetod" /> ??

Comment: No, i have no modell, im working on Dll file placed in references

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can still have a *view model*. It's just a class, but one that's not tied to the database or other datastore. Your data can come from anywhere. You just instantiate the "view model" class with the data you acquired and send the class to the view instead of a metric crap-ton of dynamics all tossed into `ViewBag`.